# Unable to retrieve Java (swt) Treeitem name (label) in Ranorex

Tags: java, swt, ranorex

I'd like to read the name (label) of the items of a tree which is implemented in Java.

When I track the tree items I only get like this: Treeitem1, Treeitem2, ...
I'd like to get the name of the tree item in order to be able to reference to them ...

Do you have an idea how can I do this?

Actually I can see the Treeitem name (label) in Spy - a bit  hidden but it is there.

Advanced - Cell TreeItem - Dynamic and there
Data - Element - ShortName

But can I retrieve the label from here - or in some other way with Ranorex for example in a C# user method ?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand of the question:

- Track the TreeItem and add it to the repository.
- Drag the TreeItem from the repository to a recording.
- Select 'Get Value' action to read the ShortName property.

Once you are able to read the ShortName of a TreeItem, you could update the reposotory item to use a variable to find the desired TreeItem.

The XPath syntax of the TreeItem could look like this:

```
//TreeItem[@shortname='ReplaceWithNameOfTreeItem']
```

Hope this helps...